# Dynamic update multible series Highcharts with single point XML file

Tags: javascript, xml, highcharts, time-series, real-time

I am a bit out of my comfort zone, since I normally do analytics and not fancy front-ends. However, I would like to have a real-time demo of some of my work, so it becomes easier to understand and not just numbers in a matrix. I have looked around and found something semi-relevant and come this far:

(It has four series like I want to and it iterates - to some degree)
https://jsfiddle.net/023sre9r/

```
var series1 = this.series[0],
series2 = this.series[1],
series3 = this.series[2],
series4 = this.series[3];
```

But I am totally lost on how to remove the random number generators without loosing nice things like the number of data points in a view (seems to depend on the for loop?!). Remove the extra title "Values" right next to my real y-axis title. And of cause how to get a new data point from a XML-file every second.

Ideally I want to have an XML-file containing 4 values, which I update approximately every 200ms in MATLAB. And every second I would like my 4 series chart to update. Is it not relatively easy, if you know what you are doing?! :-)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I simplified your example and added clear code showing how to fetch data from server and append it to your chart using series.addPoint method. Also if you want to use XML, just convert it to JS object / JSON.

```
const randomData = () => [...Array(12)]
    .map((u, i) => [new Date().getTime() + i * 1000, Math.random()])

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'spline',
    backgroundColor: null,
    animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
    marginRight: 10,
    events: {
      load () {
        const chart = this
        setInterval(() => {
            // Fetch example below (working example: https://github.com/stpoa/live-btc-chart/blob/master/app.js)
          // window.fetch('https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/btc-usd').then((response) => {
          //   return response.json()
          // }).then((data) => {
          //   chart.series[0].addPoint({ x: data.timestamp * 1000, y: Number(data.ticker.price) })
          // })

          chart.series.forEach((series) => series.addPoint([new Date().getTime(), Math.random()], true, true))

        }, 3000)
      }
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: null
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    tickPixelInterval: 150
  },
  yAxis: [{
    title: {
      text: 'Temperature [°C]',
            margin: 30
    },
    plotLines: [{
      value: 0,
      width: 1,
      color: '#808080'
    }]
  }, {

  }],
  tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
      return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
        Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 4);
    }
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: true
  },
  exporting: {
    enabled: false
  },
  rangeSelector: {
    enabled: false
  },

  navigator: {
    enabled: false
  },
  scrollbar: {
    enabled: false
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'Setpoint',
    data: randomData()
  }, {
    name: 'Return',
    data: randomData()
  }, {
    name: 'Supply',
    data: randomData()
  }, {
    name: 'Output',
    data: randomData()
  }]
})
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/9gw4ttnt/

Working one with external data source: https://jsfiddle.net/111u7nxs/